# behavior of html control in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net

Let's say I have a html input box:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>    
        <input id="Text1" type="text"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

If I type something like "My Subjects" into the input, and click the button, the text in the input box will disappear, here is something I don't quite understand:

This is a post request, since "My Subjects" will be submitted to the server, so when the server render the html, it should add the text to the input textbox and then send the html document back to the browser, is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET WebForms only adds the "postback magic" to HTML elements if they have the `runat="server"` attribute applied, otherwise they're treated as static plain text.

Add `runat="server"` and it will work:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server" />
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. So without using runat=server, the text will not post back to the server?

Comment: @slowjams As per the HTML specification, the text is always posted to the server in any valid `<input name="..." />` element contained in a valid `<form>` element - but ASP.NET WebForms won't do anything with it automatically unless it has `runat="server"`. You can still read input values using `Request.Form["name"]` without `runat="server"` but you'll have to manually render it back to the page too.

Comment: thanks again, could you also have a look at my post here, I still don't get the idea of using viewstate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402101/whats-the-purpose-to-use-viewstate-in-asp-net?noredirect=1#comment75804057_44402101

Answer (score 1):

> is my understanding incorrect?

No, I'm afraid not.  There is no mechanism by which this behavior would be *automatic*.  You would have to write code or use some tool which does this.  The ASP.NET Framework has code internally which does this for server controls, which are ones with `runat="server"`.  (See things like ViewState, and take a look at the hidden fields that ASP.NET automatically adds to your page.)

If you want to populate your page with values included in the request, you would do so in the code for that page.  To do this, first you need to give the input a `name` so it's included in the POST:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" name="Text1"/>
```

Then you can find the value server-side in the POST request with something like:

```
Request.Form["Text1"]
```

From there you can put it on the page in a variety of ways, just like any other value in your class that you want to put on the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so what does runat=server actuallt do? Is it just stopping values being posted back if not using runat=server?

Comment: @slowjams: `runat="server"` tells the ASP.NET Framework that you want the HTML element treated like a "server control".  So the framework will include it as a property of the code-behind class, perform framework-based logic on it, etc.