# What's the purpose to use Viewstate in asp. net

Tags: asp.net

It is being said that Viewstate is used to retain state between request, but let's have a scenario like this:
I have a textbox starts with 0,  and a button to increment +1. Below are steps:

1. Initially it was a get request to get the page, so the text in the textbox is 0.
2. I clicked the button, the value 0 was being postback to the server.
3. The method in the event handler on the server  increment the value by 1, then value one is sent to my browser.
4. Now the 1 was  being displayed in the textbox on my browser, and I clicked the button again, 1 is sent to the server again
5. Same as step 3, and then  I will have 2 displayed in the textbox.

As you can see, I don't need to use Viewstate to "remember" values in previous request, I know textbox in asp.net will use Viewstate by default even though enableviewstate is set to be false, so just ignore that, whatz the purpose of using viewstate in my example?

Comment: Mono has its WebForms clone which should be able to show you clearly how view state is used, https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System.Web. I don't expect you can fully understand that with only simple scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Digression:

Note that you're asking about ASP.NET WebForms, which is now effectively deprecated. It's an abstraction layer in ASP.NET which was meant to make designing [stateful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)) data entry web-pages ("web forms") easy by mimicking how VB6 and WinForms works (with "server-side events" and "controls"), however it is a very [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) which falls apart whenever you need precise control of the web-application which is why WebForms is not popular today and why ASP.NET MVC has taken its place (and [WebForms isn't even supported by ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1961) (formerly known as ASP.NET 5)).

### Back on-topic:

As you've observed, values which are directly POSTed back to the server (because they're inside `<input />` elements) do not benefit from ViewState at all - however ASP.NET WebForms' Controls have many properties and values which will not be contained within their own `<input />` element, such as (for example) `<asp:Label>`'s `Text=""` property:

I'll illustrate:

MyPage.aspx:

```
<form runat="server">
    <p>Name: <input runat="server" id="name" type="text" /></p>
    <p>Special message: <asp:Label runat="server" id="message" /></p>
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="submit" text="Set name" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="somethingElse" text="Submit form" />
</form>
```

MyPage.aspx.cs ("code-behind" page):

```
protected override void submit_ServerClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

    this.message.Text = "Congratulations to " + this.name + ", our 1,000,000th customer!"; // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suyQ44rRL5M
    this.name.Text = "";
}
```

1. If the user enters their name in the `<input id="name" />` textbox
2. then clicks the "Set name" button
3. then their name will appear in the `<asp:Label id="message" />`
4. (the code also clears the name input)
5. then if the user clicks the "Submit form" button without entering their name again, the `<asp:Label />` will retain the displayed message - even though their name was never in any of the `<input />` elements!

This works because the text of the label **was actually** resubmitted inside the hidden `__VIEWSTATE` value, and the page was reconstructed (behind the scenes, inside ASP.NET) for it to be rendered again.

Here's another way of looking at it:

```
C > S : client-to-server (web-browser to web-server)
S > C : server-to-client (web-server response to user's browser)

C > S - GET /MyPage.aspx (no form data)
S < C - OK                name="", __VIEWSTATE=""
C > S - POST /MyPage.aspx name="Foo", __VIEWSTATE=""
S < C - OK                name="", __VIEWSTATE="message.Text:\"Congratulations to foo, our 1,000,000th customer!\""
C > S - POST /MyPage.aspx name="", __VIEWSTATE="message.Text:\"Congratulations to foo, our 1,000,000th customer!\""
S < C - OK                name="", __VIEWSTATE="message.Text:\"Congratulations to foo, our 1,000,000th customer!\""
```

Even though the `name=""` field is cleared after it's set, the original supplied value ("foo") is retained in the `__VIEWSTATE` field.

Remember that `__VIEWSTATE` is an opaque blob as far as the client web-browser is concerned: it's a HMAC-signed Base64-encoded string that is not decoded or read by consumers, only by the server. Developers can also enable encryption of the `__VIEWSTATE` value (though this should have been enabled by default, IMO). It works similarly to a HTTP cookie that contains a security token. (ViewState is not compatible with cookies because it's specific to a single page, not a HTTP session, and it can often reach sizes in the *megabytes* which is too big for a cookie anyway).

I feel WebForms was an interesting experiment for the web - but it added a lot of complexity which was arguably unnecessary, and WebForms applications were inherently non-RESTful, which broke many assumptions about the web that we can now take for granted - for example, it made it almost impossible to automate web-applications through simple requests (e.g. you would need to replay every intermediate viewstate-mutating request) and if a resource was only accessible via a WebForms postback (e.g. because of a "server-side event handler") then it would break bookmarks. One particularly egregious sin was the use of `<asp:Hyperlink>` that wasn't an `<a href="">` at all, but would instead cause a POST followed by a HTTP Redirection (via `Response.Redirect` in the link's "server-side click" event handler).

Comment: don't know how to thank you, It helped a lot. Thank you so so much

Comment: just one last  clear-up question, in your example, you mentioned name="", __VIEWSTATE="", should the name be Value? since the viewstate is of label, label (whose ID is name) doesn't have a property of "name"?

Comment: @slowjams I've made my __VIEWSTATE example slightly more verbose.